# How do I safely access one Azure VM from another within a Cloud Service and Availability Set

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

I have an Azure Cloud Service, mywebapp.cloudapp.net, that consists of two Azure VMs - mywebappvm1 and mywebappvm2. Both VMs are in the same Availability Set and have the same DNS name.

I also have a Regional Reserved IP address assigned to the Cloud Service so that I can give our clients a guaranteed IP address that our app uses.

Part of the app uses a private background process, currently only running on one of the VMs. I want to be able to make a connection to that process over TCP running on mywebappvm1 from mywebappvm2. I could use the public IP and an endpoint on mywebappvm1 but I don't want the background service to be publicly accessible.

I'm currently using the private IP address, but is that safe? Will the private IP of each VM change if it's rebooted? I can't see an easy way of fixing the private IP of each VM - that seems like something you can do with a VNET but I can't find any information on how to do it with a cloud service and an availability group as well.

Is there perhaps another way to run a web app on multiple load-balanced VMs within an availability set that would make this easier?

Answer (score 2):

What you do is absolutely safe and actually a recommended best practice. You should not go out to public IP address in order to communicate between the Virtual Machines.

It is also a recommended best practice to organize your Virtual Machines into Virtual Network and sub-nets.

[This excellent blog post](http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/setting-static-ip-addresses-in-a-virtual-network/) describes how can you even use static IP addresses for the VMs, so you are always 100% sure that `mywebappvm1` always get `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` IP Address andyour `mywebappvm2` always get `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY` IP Address.

Please note that if you do not use Static IP Address assigned to the VM, it is guaranteed that the IP Address of the VM may change.

Answer (score 0):

The IP for a webRole VM instance will not change for the lifetime of the deployment regardless of reboot, update or swapping. The IP will be released only if you delete the deployment, detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/gg433027.aspx)